# Can i emit different values in mat-select?

Tags: angular, typescript

Having a code like

```
      <mat-form-field fxLayout="column" fxFlex="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%">
        <mat-select matInput id="txtAdress"
          [placeholder]="'Select' | translate: moduleName"
          [(ngModel)]="codAdress"
          (selectionChange)="onChangeLogr($event)" (onSelectionChange)="onChangeLogr_($event)">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let logr of listLogr" [value]="logr.cod">
            {{ getLogr(logr) }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Could i emit to `.ts` different values in each function? (  `(selectionChange)="onChangeLogr($event)" (onSelectionChange)="onChangeLogr_($event)"` ), where selectionChange emits one String and onSelectionChange emits one object? How?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to encapsulate `<mat-select>` into your own custom component with 2 `EventEmitter`.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by setting the second function inside `<mat-option>`, like this:

```
<mat-form-field fxLayout="column" fxFlex="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%">
        <mat-select matInput id="txtAdress"
          [placeholder]="'Select' | translate: moduleName"
          [(ngModel)]="codAdress"
          (selectionChange)="onChangeLogr($event)">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let logr of listLogr" [value]="logr.cod" (click)="onChangeLogr_(logr)">
            {{ getLogr(logr) }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
```

And, in TS file, receving `onChangeLogr($event)` and `onChangeLogr_(logr: ILogr)`.
The `click` event is also fired when an already selected option is selected again. (change) or (selectionChange) will not fire in such a case.